# Managing JavaScript hotkeys in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have the following jQuery code on a site I built:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Other Bindings/Initializations Removed

  // Hotkey Event Handler to 'doSomething'
  //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
  $(document).keypress("a",function(e) {
    if(e.altKey) { // Doesn't work
      doSomething();
    }
  });

  // Hotkey Event Handler to 'doSomething'
  //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
  $(document).keypress("a",function(e) {
    if(e.shiftKey) { //Works as Expected?
      doSomething();
    }
  });

});
```

The code catches key-press combination events, in this case "Alt-A", and then proceeds to call a function which preforms the appropriate action. I tested this feature in FireFox and the function was called as expected. When I tested the feature in Chrome the function was not called and an obnoxious error tone was emitted instead. I thought that perhaps "Alt-A" collided with an important browser hotkey combination so changed "A" to "N", "G", and then "K"; each time the function was not called and the error tone was emitted. However when I created a Shift-A/N/G/K hotkey combination, Chrome called the function as expected.

1. Why does Chrome handle the "Alt" key differently?
2. How to I define a hotkey for my site so that it will work in Chrome using the "Alt" key?

Comment: does adding: `e.preventDefault()` after `doSomething()` fix the issue?

Comment: adding e.preventDefault() after doSomething() does not fix the issue. That's for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Chrome and Firefox, however in IE Alt+a opens the favorites menu. I'm not sure how you would override that.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVxnD/1/)

HTML:

```
<a accesskey="a">​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Other Bindings/Initializations Removed
    // Hotkey Event Handler to 'doSomething'
    //-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
    $(document).keypress("a", function(e) {

        if (e.shiftKey) { //Works as Expected?
            alert("shift a");
        }

        if (e.altKey) {
            alt_a_function();
        }

    });

    $(document).on("click", "[accesskey=a]", function() {
        alt_a_function();
    });

});

function alt_a_function() {
    alert("alt a");
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery docs say that the first argument to [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) is "A map of data that will be passed to the event handler." Perhaps jQuery is confused when that object is a string, which causes an error in Chrome.

To check for a particular key in the event handler, use `e.which` to get the character code instead.

Comment: Shift+a/n/g/k works in Chrome but not Alt+a/n/g/k... why does Chrome not like the alt key?

Comment: This came up in a quick google search: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24838 That's an old ticket, but the reasons may still be the same.

Comment: Interesting, the rational "keypress is only supposed to generate 
events when the key(s) pressed would generate content" doesn't seem to hold because Shift & Ctrl keys appear to be generating keyPress events and they would fall into the same category as the Alt key; not generating content. Still this may be the problem, a Chrome browser defect.

Comment: edit or create a new answer including a reference to the Chrome browser defect regarding the Alt key and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I can post an answer claiming a Chrome defect :-) According to the W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress "A user agent must dispatch this event when a key is pressed down, if and only if that key normally produces a character value."

Comment: Really they all should act the same whether or not they comply with W3C standards because they are "almost" always used in the same context.

Comment: I'm not sure, it is a little fiddly to say. On my Mac, in Chrome, Alt+A inserts "å" and fires keypress, Shift+A inserts "A" and fires keypress. When focus is inside textboxes, Ctrl+A moves the selection to the start of the text box and does not fire keypress, and Ctrl+Shift+A selects to the start of the textbox and does not fire keypress. With focus outside textboxes, Ctrl+A and Ctrl+Shift+A do fire keypress, but they have a strange event.which value, which I don't fully understand. Other OS's will be different, but this seems standards compliant to me, at least with focus inside textboxes.