# Stop the Binging Noise when alt is used in a hotkey

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

When you press alt+almost Any other key it makes binging noise. The noise says "you've tried to do something you can't"

I'd like to use the alt key in several combinations as a keyboard shortcut for a web app.

Despite there being something to do when alt+* is hit the bing is persistent.

Is there a way to keep the bing from sounding in JavaScript?

Edit: <strike>This is probably just a windows issue</strike> This is an issue in chrome.

Comment: I hear no binging whatsoever.

Comment: For me it only happens in Chrome. FF and IE and Windows 7 desktop do not make the ding.

Comment: I hear no binging in Chrome either.

Comment: @Pointy Click on the document and press an invalid command e.g. Alt+H.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Chrome/Linux does not "bing".

Comment: Yes, I should mention this is probably just a windows issue.

Comment: Further inspection reveals that it's a Chrome/Windows feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that registering the key you wish to use as an accessKey will prevent chrome from emitting the Error noise *BING*.

Problem has been solved by using a very blank anchor tag with the accessKey assigned to my desired hot key.

```
<a accessKey=*>
```

Solution discovered thanks to this post:
[Managing JavaScript hotkeys in Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655493/managing-javascript-hotkeys-in-chrome-browser)